# 'input' works in 3.5 IDLE but not in the terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, io, terminal

Here is some basic code I've made:

```
userInput = input("Type in a random word:\n")
print("Here are the letters in that word")
for letters in userInput:
    print(letters)
```

Completely works in the 3.5 shell/IDLE but wont work in my terminal...
Here is the error when i put the input as "test":

```
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

Any help?

Comment: Are you doing this in the `python` console (i.e., at the `>>>` prompt)? Using a raw input reader (like the `input()` function) in the Python 3 REPL is problematic, because the REPL is already reading raw input. Try putting the same code in a file (e.g., "foo.py") and running it (e.g., `python3 foo.py`). That works fine for me on my machine.

Comment: No, I saved it as ForLoopTest.py and it still gives me the error in terminal. Also this error persists in a lot of my practice files when I get user input.

Comment: Run `python -V` to see the version of the interpreter you are running in your terminal.

Comment: Oh I see. It says I'm running Python 2.7.5 How do I change that

Comment: Check if Python 3 is installed: `which python3`. If it is you run your program `python3 foo.py` as @BrianClapper mentioned above. If it's not available, you'll have to install Python 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the terminal you are really running Python 2.  `raw_input()` in Python 2 is the equivalent to `input()` in Python 3.  `input()` in Python 2 will evaluate the input as a Python statement, so it tries to evaluate `test` as a variable name.

If you are using Windows you can use the Python Launcher (py.exe) to specify the version of Python to run if you have multiple versions installed.  It should already be in the path if you've installed Python 3.  In Linux `python3` should work.

Example:

```
C:\>py -3
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> input()
test
'test'
>>> ^Z

C:\>py -2
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> input()
test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

You are running the code using Python 2 the second time. Instead of using the command python, you can use python3 which should work.

In Python 2 you should use `raw_input()` instead, as the input function includes a call to the `eval()` function which attempts to execute the input as Python code. `raw_input()` takes the input as a string. In Python 3 `raw_input()` has been replaced by `input()`.

Comment: @G.Grasso you went from an answer that provided a good explanation, to one that just mentions the versions of Python and not the reasons why.

Comment: `str(input())` in Python 2 will still try to evaluate the input and give the same error.  `raw_input()` is correct for Python 2 and is equivalent to `input()` in Python 3.

Comment: I have fixed it as you described. You were right, my mistake.