# input functions are not working in IDLE shell

Tags: python

Input functions are not working in IDLE shell. I try to use them but it keeps giving me a error.

I was expecting the inputs to work.

Comment: How do you expect us to help without showing us the code or the error?  Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: I attached a image but it did not show

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you could post your code and screenshots of the error message. However, my guess would be that you are using a different python version in your shell. Try visiting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582956/input-works-in-3-5-idle-but-not-in-the-terminal), could be solution to your problem.

Comment: Here is the error: >>> print('Enter your name:')
... x = input()
... print('Hello, ' + x)
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Comment: This is not an answer.  But since you posted it an an answer, this question is now marked in the system as being "answered", so fewer people are going to look at it...